# Draconic Frenzy and multi strike penalty

Tags: pathfinder-2e

Am I seeing it correctly that draconic frenzy does NOT mitigate the strike penalty. Thus for the 3 strikes you still suffer them for the 2nd and 3rd strike granted by draconic frenzy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

Because there is no specification that it does not suffer the penalty, it does suffer the penalty. Abilities that do not will say so explicitly (such as Fighters' [Double Slice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=356))